# Can we add WM_POINTERDOWN message to a window win32 ListView controls?

Tags: listview, winapi, window, controls, win32gui

Since touch devices are very popular, can we add a wm_pointerdown/up message to listview controls?

I have tried to do it like this:

```
case WM_POINTERDOWN:
    {
        SendMessage(hWndListView,WM_POINTERDOWN,wParam,lParam);
        break;
    }
    case WM_POINTERUP:
    {
        SendMessage(hWndListView,WM_POINTERUP,wParam,lParam);
        break;
    }
```

but there is no NM_MOUSEDOWN message in <commctrl.h>, NM_CLICK exist insteadly;

Comment: Why are you trying to handle this manually, instead of letting the OS handle and translate the user input for you?

Comment: Do you insist to use `WM_POINTERDOWN`? `NM_CLICK` is enough, isn’t It?